# Subset dataframe by row names

Tags: r, subset

I'd like to subset a dataframe by a range of row names.  But I keep getting this error message:

```
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

my data looks like this:

```
              KATstd samp.depth
    1800 0.4015238          8
    1801 1.2792888          8
    1802 1.5981420          8
    1803 1.9429598          8
    1804 2.7847786          9
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
KAT.sub<-subset(KAT,row.names==(1929:2009))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `KAT[1929:2009,]`. The `==` logical equivalence operator is not "vectorized" and you cannot refer to the row.names of a data.frame like that. You may want to brush up on basic subsetting by looking at `? extract`.